# Python, if 'word' is in link print link else if '2ndword' in link print that one

Tags: python, loops, if-statement, hyperlink

So I have made a python spider which gets all links from given site and then prints out that one which contains `'impressum'` in itself. Now I wanted to make an `elif` function which prints out link that contains `'kontakt'` in istelf if that one with `'impressum'` was not found in links. My code for now looks like this:

```
import urllib
import re
import mechanize
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urlparse
import cookielib
from urlparse import urlsplit
from publicsuffix import PublicSuffixList

url = "http://www.zahnarztpraxis-uwe-krause.de"

br = mechanize.Browser()
cj = cookielib.LWPCookieJar()
br.set_cookiejar(cj)
br.set_handle_robots(False)
br.set_handle_equiv(False)
br.set_handle_redirect(True)
br.set_handle_refresh(mechanize._http.HTTPRefreshProcessor(), max_time=1)
br.addheaders = [('User-agent', 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; U; Linux i686; en-US; rv:1.9.0.1) Gecko/2008071615 Fedora/3.0.1-1.fc9 Firefox/3.0.1')]
page = br.open(url, timeout=5)

htmlcontent = page.read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(htmlcontent)

newurlArray = []

for link in br.links(text_regex=re.compile('^((?!IMG).)*$')):
    newurl = urlparse.urljoin(link.base_url, link.url)
    if newurl not in newurlArray:
        newurlArray.append(newurl)
        #print newurl
        if 'impressum' in newurl:
            print newurl

        elif 'impressum' not in newurl and 'kontakt' in newurl:
            print newurl
```

and despite of that `if` `elif` loop I'm always getting both links in console:

```
http://www.zahnarztpraxis-uwe-krause.de/pages/kontakt.html
http://www.zahnarztpraxis-uwe-krause.de/pages/impressum.html
```

but in true situation I need second with 'kontakt' only if 'impressum was not found.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I can't understand what you're trying to do. You print the URL in both cases, whether it has "kontakt" or "impressum". What are you expecting to happen?

Comment: You don't need to check again if 'impressum' is not in the link, since it will only reach the `elif` if the `if 'impressum' in newurl` evaluates to false (i.e. 'impressum' isn't in your URL). But I don't understand what you're trying to achieve, aren't the results you're getting correct anyway?

Comment: so I'm tying to achieve that I get impressum if it exists, if impressum does not exists that spider search for kontakt. In my way I'm getting a both results, even the impressum is there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You see both links because they are occurring in separate iterations of the `for` loop.  A single `if` block only looks at a single URL, and the `elif` makes sure that single URL isn't printed twice in case it contains both `"impressum"` and `"kontakt"`.  It doesn't prevent more links from being printed in later iterations.

To achieve what you want you first have to loop over all links and decide after the loop what to print, since you want to give precedence to `"impressum"` in any case.  You can only know whether there is an `"impressum"` after you've seen all links:

```
urls = set()
contact_keys = ["impressum", "kontakt"]
found_contact_urls = {}
for link in ...:
    new_url = ...
    urls.add(new_url)
    for key in contact_keys:
        if key in new_url:
            found_contact_urls[key] = new_url
            break
for key in contact_keys:
    if key in found_contact_urls:
        print found_contact_urls[key]
        break
```

This code allows to add further fall-back strings to the list `contact_keys`.

Comment: what should go in place of second `...`?

on place of first I suppose that I must set some list or something.

Comment: Your original code.  I just didn't bother to copy it there. :)

Comment: if I put `for link in newurlArray:` and `new_url = link` I'm getting a result like this: 

`http://www.zahnarztpraxis-uwe-krause.de/pages/kontakt.html
http://www.zahnarztpraxis-uwe-krause.de/pages/impressum.html
http://www.zahnarztpraxis-uwe-krause.de/pages/impressum.html`

and if I put `for link in newurlArray:` and `new_url = newurl` I get same result as for my original code. So I am doing something wrong?

Comment: By "original code" I meant the code you posted.  `urls` is a replacement for `newurlArray` -- it's more efficient to use a `set` here.  And what do you mean by "result"?  My code will definitely only print a single URL, because there is only a single `print` statement with a `break` clause after it.  Are you sure you got the indentation right?

Comment: not sure what is problem in my edition of code... must check it once more. Could you post your whole code on http://pastebin.com or something?

Comment: Yea, I've managed to get it right! Thank you, this is what was I looking for

Answer (score 1):

I *think* I understand what you're trying to achieve, you only want to print one of those URLs per page; always print the `impressum` link even if `kontakt` is also on the page, and in the case `impressum` isn't on the page then print `kontakt`, correct?

If so, you could either add a flag to say whether `impressum` is on the page and thus which URL to print, or populate a single variable and print that, as follows:

```
myUrl = "" #somewhere at start of processing where it is only set to "" once
    #in loop:
    if 'impressum' in newurl:
        myUrl = newurl
    elif not myUrl and 'kontakt' in newurl:
        myUrl = newurl
print myUrl #print after entire page has been processed
```

This is untested but something similar should work

Answer (score 0):

```
    if 'impressum' in newurl:
        print newurl
    elif 'kontakt' in newurl:
        print 'Not impressum:'
        print newurl
```

I didn't see any way you distinguish from which "if" case cough the link, so try this and you'll see if it's the `if` or `elif` block printing the link.

And as @Joshua writes, you don't need to do "`'impressum' not in newurl`" Since it's already been checked in the `if` block.

Answer (score 0):

```
if 'impressum' in newurl:
    print "Impressum:", newurl

elif 'kontakt' in newurl:
    print "Kontakt:", newurl
else:
    pass // not impressum and not kontakt
```

The `elif` will get only executed it the if above fails, so you don't need a *double* check there.

**Edit:**

If you want the spider stop crawling after it found the link, change your code to that:

```
if 'impressum' in newurl:
    print "Impressum:", newurl
    break

elif 'kontakt' in newurl:
    print "Kontakt:", newurl
    break
else:
    pass // not impressum and not kontakt
```

Comment: it gives me a practicaly same results... I'm getting both links... It seems to me that problem is that spider first finds link with kontakt and then he thinks that impressum does not exist, and on second pass he finds impressum and prints it too..

Comment: You get both links because one link contains "kontakt" and one "impressum".

Comment: Yea, and I want that if impressum is found it does not search for kontakt but my program does